# Use Mac OS in virtual machine on Windows?

Tags: mac, windows, bootcamp

I just got MacBook Pro 2011 and installed Windows 7 using Boot Camp.

I am a Windows user who need to develop iOS apps.

Is it possible to install Mac OS VM on Windows that is installed using Boot Camp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various (hacky) ways to do this

eg http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2010/07/how-to-run-mac-os-x-in-virtualbox-on-windows/

But I would urge you to install VirtualBox in Mac OS X and then install Windows on that.  You can run Windows full screen.  It's going to be very quick and allow you the best of both worlds.

Best of all VirtualBox is free and available here http://www.virtualbox.org/

Comment: Agreed with RobZolkos, VirtualBox is one of the best free application available.

Answer (score 1):

Check following articles, they might help you if you are not comfortable with LifeHacker solution

http://oreilly.com/windows/archive/PearPC.html

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XD2F_S-zsuw   (video link)